# How to render a JS object with underscore templates?

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I'm trying to render a JS object of data using underscore templates and Backbone.js.

I created data it like below picture.

[image: JS object data]

and then, i saw the similar question.
[How to display a JS object with underscore templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31024786/how-to-display-a-js-object-with-underscore-templates)

I hadn't known Backbone.js collection and model correctly, but recently I understood those.
I has made data inserting the collection that like below source code.

```
//that's create view
wordCollection.add(wordList);
var view = new views.Livingword({collection:wordList});

//that's view 
render: function(templateName) {
        var template = _.template(templateName);
        this.$el.html(template({result : this.collection.category}));
        return this;
      }
```

then, i wrote the html source code.

```
  <% _.each(result, function(item,key,list){ %>
            <tr>
            <td><%- category[key].bedroom %></td>
            </tr>
          <% }) %>
```

but, error is printing `Uncaught ReferenceError: category is not defined`
so i try to debug `collection` resulting from the console command when i running 
`console.log(this.collection.category);` is below picture.
[image: this.collection.category result]

I think creating data is appropriate and don't find incorrect source code.
How can i render my data in html?

Comment: You are passing `this.collection.category` as `result` to template. So, you should use `result[key]..` instead of `category[key]..`, right? `category` should be `undefined` in template scope

Comment: Oh my god.. lol really thanks

Comment: @RaR hmm.. error is handled but, nothing displayed.. i type `<%- result[key].audioSrc %>` what's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In each of the iterations, `item` in your code will be values of stuff like "bedroom", which are arrays containing objects.
So in order to go through and print each items inside it, you need another iteration.

```
<% _.each(result, function(arr, key, list){ %>
 <!-- Add <tbody>, <thead> etc with "key" here -->

  <% _.each(arr, function(item, key, list){ %>
     <tr>
        <td><%= item.audioSrc %></td>
     </tr>
  <% }) %>

<% }) %>
```

Now in the above code, `audioSrc` is hardcoded. If you know all the properties you want to print, you can do that. If you don't (they are dynamic), then you need another iteration to go through each properties of item.

Side notes:

- Instead of executing `var template = _.template(templateName);` on every render, do

  ```
  template: _.template(templateName), // one time
  render: function(templateName) { 
      this.$el.html(this.template({result: this.collection.category}));
      return this;
  }
  ```
- Give meaningful names to things you pass into template. `result` is a vague name. `category` is better, but it being a map of categories, proper naming would be `categories`. So `this.template({categories: this.collection.category}`. If the names are clear you'd have a better idea of what you're doing while writing the template
- Based on the usage: `this.collection.category`, I'm pretty sure it should be a model and not collection. Collection is for group of things and you'd be using it's models array like `this.collection.models`.
  So with all the changes your code should be something like

  ```
  template: _.template(templateName), // one time
  render: function(templateName) { 
      this.$el.html(this.template({categories: this.model.categories});
      // ---- This can be an Array or Collection instance -----^
      return this;
  }
  ```

  With template:

  ```
  <% _.each(categories, function(category, name){ %>
  <!-- Add <tbody>, <thead> etc with "name" here -->

    <% _.each(category, function(item, name){ %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= item.audioSrc %></td>
      </tr>
    <% }) %>

  <% }) %>
  ```